# Cerrar modal después de guardar en la BD

Tags: php, bootstrap, angularjs

Tengo un modal con un formulario, el cual se debe cerrar una vez se guarde la información en la BD, esto ocurre perfectamente cuando se diligencian todos los campos del formulario, pero cuando dejo en blanco un campo que no es requerido, se guarda el registro en la BD pero el modal no se cierra automáticamente.

Este es el código en el app.js en el que hago la validación de la respuesta del api que tiene el query, hice un console.log cuando se llenan todos los campos llega la respuesta 201, pero cuando no diligencio el campo no me llega respuesta

```
 $scope.guardarVisitasEnConjunto = function(visitasEnConjunto, frmVisitasEnConjunto) {
    //console.log("visitasEnConjuntoALEX: ", visitasEnConjunto );
    services.guardarFormVisitasEnConjunto(visitasEnConjunto).then(
        function(respuesta) {
            console.log("respuesta", respuesta.status);
            if (respuesta.status == '201') {
                Swal(
                    'La visita en conjunto fue Guardada!',
                    'Bien Hecho'
                )
            } else if (respuesta.status == '200') {
                Swal(
                    'La visita en conjunto fue Guardada!',
                    'Bien Hecho'
                )
            }
            /*PARA QUE EL MODAL SE OCULTE SOLO*/
            $("#modalVisitasEnConjunto").modal('hide');
            $scope.visitasEnConjuntoSel = {};
            /*LIMPIEZA DEL MODAL*/
            frmVisitasEnConjunto.autoValidateFormOptions.resetForm();
        },
        function errorCallback(response) {
            if (response.status == '400') {
                Swal({
                    type: 'error',
                    title: 'Oops...',
                    text: 'Esta visita en conjunto ya está registrada!',
                    footer: '¡Recuerda cada visita es única!'
                })
            }
        });
    $scope.RegistrosVisitasEnConjunto(visitasEnConjunto);
}
```

Este es el codigo en el php.

```
private function infoVisitasEnConjunto() {

    if ($this->get_request_method() != "POST") {
        $this->response('', 406);
    }

    $this->dbSeguimientoConnect();

    $params = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    $datos = $params['datosEdicion'];

    //$key = $datos['key'];
    $pedido = $datos['pedido'];
    $tecnicopremisas = $datos['tecnicoPremisas'];
    $tecnicoinfraestructura = $datos['tecnicoInfraestructura'];
    $fechavisita = $datos['fechaVisita'];
    $region = $datos['region'];
    $ciudad = $datos['ciudad'];
    $contrato = $datos['contrato'];
    $gestion = $datos['gestion'];
    $quiensolicitavisita = $datos['solicita'];
    $notas = $datos['notas'];
    $grupo = $datos['grupo'];
    $fechafingestion = $datos['fechafinGestion'];

    if (isset($datos['id'])) {

        $sqlUpdate = ("
            UPDATE seguimientopedidos.visitasenconjunto v
            SET v.pedido                    = TRIM('$pedido'),
                v.tecnicopremisas           = LOWER(TRIM('$tecnicoPremisas')),
                v.tecnicoinfraestructura    = LOWER(TRIM('$tecnicoInfraestructura')),
                v.fechavisita               = TRIM('$fechaVisita'),
                v.region                    = LOWER(TRIM('$region')),
                v.ciudad                    = LOWER(TRIM('$ciudad')),
                v.contrato                  = (TRIM('$contrato')),
                v.gestion                   = (TRIM('$gestion')),
                v.quiensolicitavisita       = LOWER(TRIM('$solicita')),
                v.notas                     = (TRIM('$notas')),
                v.grupo                     = (TRIM('$grupo')),
                v.fechasolicitud            = NOW(),
                v.fechafingestion           = TRIM('$fechafinGestion')

            WHERE v.id = $key
        ");

        $rst = $this->connseguimiento->query($sqlUpdate);


        if (is_numeric($rst) OR $rst === true) {
            $this->response($this->json('Pedido actualizado'), 201);
        } else {
            $this->response($this->json("Error"), 400);
        }

    } else {

        $sqlInsetar = ("
                INSERT INTO visitasenconjunto
                (   pedido, tecnicopremisas, tecnicoinfraestructura , fechavisita, region, ciudad, contrato, gestion, quiensolicitavisita, notas, grupo, fechasolicitud, fechafingestion)
                VALUES
                (   TRIM('$pedido'), LOWER(TRIM('$tecnicopremisas')), LOWER(TRIM('$tecnicoinfraestructura')), TRIM('$fechavisita'), LOWER(TRIM('$region')), LOWER(TRIM('$ciudad')),
                    (TRIM('$contrato')), (TRIM('$gestion')), LOWER(TRIM('$quiensolicitavisita')), (TRIM('$notas')), (TRIM('$grupo')), NOW(), TRIM('$fechafingestion') 
                )
            ");

        $rst = $this->connseguimiento->query($sqlInsetar);
        //echo json_encode($rst);


        if (is_numeric($rst) OR $rst === true) {
            $this->response($this->json('Pedido actualizado'), 201);
        } else {
            $this->response($this->json("Error"), 400);
        }
    }

}
```

Este es el HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Fecha Fin Gestión</label><br>
  <input style="width:240px" type="text" name="fechafingestion" id="fechafingestion" class="form-control btn btn-default" ng-model="visitasEnConjuntoSel.fechafinGestion" placeholder="Fecha Fin Gestión" datetime-picker="" date-format="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss">&nbsp<i class="fa fa-calendar fa-lg"></i>
</div>
```

Saludos cordiales

Comment: saludos te sugiero cambiar el orden de "$("#modalVisitasEnConjunto").modal('hide');"

Comment: dicha linea colocala dentro de los if : if (respuesta.status == '201') {...aqui...}else if(respuesta.status == '200'){...y aqui....}....ojo el swal viene despues de la sentencia que oculta tu modal..!!

Comment: @Diego Avila gracias por tu respuesta, hice lo que sugieres pero el comportamiento sigue igual, guarda el registro en la BD pero el modal no se oculta.

Comment: primer revisa tu id de la modal que sea el correcto, otra seria probar mediante la clase "$('.modal.in').modal('hide') "...

Comment: Buenos días he probado varias sugerencias de este post y otros con un problema similiar y no logro solucionarlo, ya identifique que para que se guarde el modal y los datos es necesario llenar un campo fecha que tengo en el formulario del modal, de lo contrario me ejecuta el mensaje de que se guardaron los datos pero no viajan a la BD

Comment: ¿Podrias agregar también tú codigo HTML para ver si ahi no se encuentra algún problema?Saludos

Comment: @cjara acabo de agregar el HTML

Answer (score 1):

Podrías utilizar angular.element para obtener una referencia a tú elemento y poder ocultarlo.
Realice un ejemplo en donde se abre el modal al iniciar la aplicación y lo cierra despues de 5seg.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>
            Bootstrap Example
        </title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
                <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
                    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
                    </script>
                    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">
                    </script>
                    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js">
                    </script>
                </link>
            </meta>
        </meta>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog" id="myModal">
                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">
                                ×
                            </button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">
                               Header modal
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>
                                Body modal
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">
                                Cerrar
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module("app", []); 
              app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
                   this.$onInit = function () {
                    //Se abre el modal
                   var element = angular.element('#myModal');
                   element.modal('show');
                   //Se cierra despues de 5 segundos
                   setTimeout(function(){
                      element.modal('hide');
                   }, 5000);
                  }
      });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```